# removing data frame rows based on separate dataframe

Tags: r

I have two data frames looking like this

```
interactions <-data.frame(predator=c('A','A','B','B','C'),Prey=c('A','B','C','D','D'))

site.species <- data.frame(species=c('B','C','D'))

> interactions
  predator Prey
1        A    A
2        A    B
3        B    C
4        B    D
5        C    D

> site.species
  species
1       B
2       C
3       D
```

I'd like to remove all the rows in the interactions data frame that have terms not included in the site.species data frame (so rows 1 and 2 in this case). How would i go about this?

Comment: Which column of the interactions data frame are you checking?

Comment: i'd like to remove all rows in the interaction df that contain values not on the site.species df so i'd like to check both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can determine if the values of `interactions` are members of the `site.species` data frame with the following -

```
(ss <- sapply(interactions, "%in%", site.species$species))
#      predator  Prey
# [1,]    FALSE FALSE
# [2,]    FALSE  TRUE
# [3,]     TRUE  TRUE
# [4,]     TRUE  TRUE
# [5,]     TRUE  TRUE
```

This gives us a logical matrix which we can use for checking. When the row sum is 2 (the number of columns of `interactions`) then we know all the values in that row are in the `site.species` data frame.

```
rowSums(ss) == 2
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

We can use that for our subset.

```
interactions[rowSums(ss) == 2, ]
#   predator Prey
# 3        B    C
# 4        B    D
# 5        C    D
```

Comment: this works great Richard, thanks for the explanation too!

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `&` and `%in%`

```
interactions[with(interactions, predator %in% site.species[[1]] & 
             Prey %in% site.species[[1]]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

interactions %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n() ) %>%
  gather(role, species, -ID) %>%
  right_join(site.species) %>%
  spread(role, species) %>%
  filter(complete.cases(.) )
```

Comment: I get an error when i run this, how would i do it exactly with the data shown above?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the name of the dataset to interactions, does that help?

Comment: Where is `complete_cases` from?  If you meant `complete.cases`, then that actually does not work either.

Comment: Oops, I had to add an ID variable. And yeah, I meant complete.cases